# Load Images from within CSS resources in JSF 2.0

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, resources

I am new to JavaServer Faces and I'm trying to do the following:

The template file "/template.xhtml" loads a stylesheet using

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="style" name="default.css" />
```

Within that CSS file I want to link to images like so:

```
... background-image: url(LINK_TO_MY_IMAGE) ...
```

How do I reference that image (what should I write into LINK_TO_MY_IMAGE)?
I already tried to use the direct link (*/contextroot/resources/images/foo.png*) and the JSF resources notation (*/contextroot/faces/javax.faces.resource/foo.png?ln=images*).

My directory structure:

```
/resources/images  => contains image files
/resources/style/default.css
/WEB-INF/web.xml
/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
/template.xhtml
/demoPage.xhtml  => uses the template.xhtml
```

So, my problem so far is that I always get a "404 Not Found" for loading that images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add css into your XHTML

```
<link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and in CSS

```
background-image: /resources/images/someName.png
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. I just had a typo in my CSS file ..

Comment: But... adding a "/" at the begining wouldn't reference this as the context root y Tomcat? I mean. If you have the application deployed under <Tomcat_Root>/myapplication, would this solution work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

After much experimentation this works in the CSS:

> ```
> url("msgError.gif.xhtml?ln=images")
> ```

In the above, msgError.gif is my resource located at /resources/images/msgError.gif
I believe the .xhtml is just used to use the JSF FacesServlet (see web.xml)

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The "ln" is the library name.

Comment: You should be using `#{resource}`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/changing-the-image-of-a-hcommandbutton-using-css/6926193#6926193

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there are so many different ways... but here is another path that works with inline CSS.

```
<div style="background-image: url('/javax.faces.resource/images/someName.png.xhtml');">
    Text to Display
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SASS (SCSS) mixin**

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// resource_url function returns the parameter as url(#{resource['<parameter>']})
// and should be used instead of CSS url() or compass image_url() in JSF applications.
// Define JSF Resource Library resource['standard:

@function resource_url($url) {
  @return url + "(\#{resource['test:#{$url}']})";
}
```

**Usage:**

```
background: resource_url('img/footer_trenner.gif') no-repeat center left;
```