# Should I use URLs as links to images and other resources or should I use the EL #{resource...}

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I save images, css, and javascript (the folders has the same name) files in a resource folder in the webapp root. Should I be using URLs to get show the image in for example a graphicImage tag or should I be using the `#{resources:libraryName..}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the therefor provided [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html), [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) and [`<h:graphicImage>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) components wherein you specify a path relative to the resources folder in the `name` attribute:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="images/logo.png" />
```

JSF will worry about setting the right URL.

The `#{resource}` syntax is only necessary inside CSS files to reference background images.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/changing-the-image-of-a-hcommandbutton-using-css/)

Comment: Ah, okey. So thats what the #{resource} is for. Thank you.

Comment: But what if the image is made with regular img-tag (its a template). Should I change to using the JSF equivalent? If not do I need to append "resources" in front off css/js/images?

Comment: You should definitely change it by the therefor intended JSF component. Otherwise you indeed need to bring in some ugly boilerplate code to get the relative URL right for every single instance of the raw HTML element.

Comment: Not when the JSF page is by itself inside a folder. You'd need to change the image URL to point to a domain-relative URL `<img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/nav/settings.png" />`. Those JSF components removes exactly this boilerplate and worriness from your hands and you also end up with less code.

Comment: Oh, I see. Great help as allways!