# In JSF, can I suppress part of the directory hierarchy of an XHTML file in the URL?

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, servlets, url-mapping

In a JSF application, we have the directory hierarchy:

```
webapp
  xhtml
    login.xhtml
    main.xhtml
    search.xhtml
  css
    main.css
    extra.css
  js
    jquery.js
```

etc. The servlet mapping is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works fine, but the URLs of our web app look like this:

```
http://localhost/myapp/xhtml/login.xhtml
http://localhost/myapp/xhtml/search.xhtml
```

We would like to have simpler URLs by dropping the `/xhtml` part, i.e.
    http://localhost/myapp/login.xhtml

I could not find any way to accomplish this. Is there some way to do this in the `<servlet-mapping>`? Do I need some additional framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it with a `Filter`. Either homegrown or a 3rd party one like [URLRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/). Just map it on `*.xhtml` and then forward to `/xhtml/*`.

Something like:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

String ctx = request.getContextPath();
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String viewId = uri.substring(ctx.length(), uri.length());

if (viewId.startsWith("/xhtml")) {
    // Redirect to URL without /xhtml (changes URL in browser address bar).
    response.setStatus(301);
    response.setHeader("Location", ctx + viewId.substring("/xhtml".length());
    // Don't use response.sendRedirect() as it does a temporary redirect (302).
} else {
    // Forward to the real location (doesn't change URL in browser address bar).
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/xhtml" + viewId).forward(request, response);
}
```

But simpler would be to just change the directory hierarchy to get rid of `/xhtml` subfolder. Those CSS/JS (and image) files should preferably be placed in a `/resources` subfolder so that you can utilize the powers of `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>` in a proper way.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)
- [Should I use URLs as links to images and other resources or should I use the EL #{resource...}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538484/should-i-use-urls-as-links-to-images-and-other-resources-or-should-i-use-the-el)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It's good to know I can use a filter, but if the recommended way is to put the XHTMLs directly into `webapp/`, I think that's what we'll do. No need to overcomplicate things...