# How to override stylesheets of PrimeFaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Simply i tried to look the name of a component in generated HTML through FireBug after that i change it in my manually defined css in JSF project, but could not override the PrimeFaces' CSS definition. Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If using primefaces 2.2.1, Use the h:outputStylesheet tag and include it in h:body not in h:head to override primefaces stylesheets, same with h:outputScript.

Example:

```
<h:body>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="YOURSTYLES.css" />
  <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="YOURSCRIPT.js" target="head" />
</h:body>
```

If using primefaces 3, follow this blog entry
https://www.primefaces.org/resource-rendering/

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i can understand **nothing** from advised blog even tough it is on primefaces domain. i want to ask: should i write my style.css including line in a facet, shuld i name it with first. but it is in head. there is a late order "head content" entry in the queue, blog writer defined. thanks for any little explanation

Comment: If you are using primefaces3, then currently this feature is not working with resource API so refrain from using h:outputStylesheet and h:outputScript tags. You can use middle/last depending on ur need. The way you can get this to work is like this         <f:facet name="last">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/styles.css" />
        <title>Webapp</title>
       </f:facet>

Comment: By the way if you do not want it to be in the middle of PF-CSS and PF-JS, and your only need is to be at the last. Then use the solution for primefaces 2.2.1. That way you can use resource API too. It works for primefaces 3 also.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer accepted, if it has helped you in solving the problem

Answer (score 8):

Adding to what @Ravi already answered:

From primefaces 3.0 on you can customize the order of the resources. However when I tried that it was not working at first.

It turned out that I could not use the JSF component to include css like this:

```
<f:facet name="last">
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
</f:facet>
```

Instead I had to use:

```
<f:facet name="last">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />
</f:facet>
```

Only then the ordering started to work.

**EDIT**: My answer is superfluous if you put the `facet` into the `body` (instead of `head`). Just like Ravi wrote in his answer. (I must have missed that somehow.)

It also not advisable to do this because then the resources are not processed by the `FacesServlet` and problems with paths inside of css can come up. Compare this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926193/332248) from BalusC.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Did you find a way in the meantime to do this with an h:outputStylesheet?

Comment: No, I haven't looked into this again.

Comment: @DominikObermaier: I edited my answer. You can use `h:outputStylesheet` but you will have to put it into the `body`.

Comment: To me when I used <f:facet name="last"> I had to use the css include in the JSF format. Not like <link ... >

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your CSS file link comes after the PrimeFaces file in your code.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/showcase-labs/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/showcase-labs/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.0-SNAPSHOT" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="YOURSTYLES.CSS" />
```

In addition, while it is not generallythe preferred solution you can add !important after your styles to give them the highest priority: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: thanks for reply but there is no line like <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/showcase-labs/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/showcase-labs/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.0-SNAPSHOT" />
 in my project. even i searched

Answer (score 0):

Try to create more specific CSS rules for your overrides.

The easiest way is to prepend PrimeFaces CSS definitions by a specific id which is used only on your pages:

```
#tuxi_site .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
   ...
}
```

Read more about CSS Specificity in "[CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)" article.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to use a more well defined (stronger) selector. The more specific your CSS is, the higher importance the interpreter will grant to it. Please see this article on CSS Cascading Order: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Or if you are in a rush: http://ww.boogiejack.com/CSS_4.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override primefaces.css, you can do it by creating blank resouces/primefaces/primefaces.css . It's not perfect but working with Primefaces 5.0