# Removing Primefaces CSS layout from JSF page

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page with from. I also use Primefaces. At the bottom of the page I have two buttons which execute the JSF form:

```
<div id="settingstwodivthree" style="width:400px; height:60px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:380px; left:800px">
    <p:commandButton value="Save Settings" id="ajax" actionListener="#{GeneralController.updateDBSettings}" rendered="true" update="growl,settingsupdate"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Default Settings" id="defaultsettings" actionListener="#{GeneralController.defaultSettings}" rendered="true" update="settingsupdate"/>                  
</div>
```

When I add Primefaces into the JSF page the default layout of the button is changed. It seems that css file from Primefaces is overriding the layout of the buttons.

I added this into the `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But the problem is still there. Is there any way some how to disable the css overriding?

Comment: The styles on the div will be applied but if you have defined styles for the buttons in a separate stylesheet then see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578494/how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces/8581199#8581199

Comment: Which version of primefaces are you using? The primefaces.THEME setting had some problems in some versions. Agree also with Ravi about CSS. Define your CSS Styles directly in p:commandbutton

Comment: I use the latest stable - 3.3.1

Comment: Read through the PF documentation there you will find a section called Skinning for each component and then apply your styles on the <p:commandButton> itself

Answer (score 7):

hi i had the same problem with the remaining primefaces.css, i solved it by placing an empty file in this folder, to override the primefaces file

```
WebContent\resources\primefaces\primefaces.css
```