# How to abandon the transparency of a PrimeFaces Dialog?

Tags: jsf, mobile, jsf-2, dialog, primefaces

I'm trying to display an alert using **Primefaces Dialog** component in my JSF page. I could display the dialog, but my problem is with the transparency/opacity of this dialog. I have overridden the style property of the dialog by setting `opacity: 1.0`, but it didn't work. I want to abandon the dialog's transparency. How can I achieve this in a simple way?

My JSF page:

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
....
renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE">
....
<pm:page title="Mobile Reports">
<pm:view id="reports" swatch="b">
<h:form>
<pm:content>
<div>
<h:form>
    ....
    <p:dialog id="myDialog"
        header="ERROR"
        widgetVar="dlg"
        modal="true"
        style="opacity: 1.0;"
        appendToBody="true">
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Couldn't display the report!"
            onclick="dlg.hide()" type="button" />
    </p:dialog>
    ....
    <p:commandButton id="contractInfo" action="ContractInfo.xhtml"
        value="Contract Information" style="width:100%;"
        onerror="dlg.show();">
    </p:commandButton>
    ....
</h:form>
</div>
</pm:content>
</h:form>
</pm:view>
</pm:page>
</f:view>
```

Output:

[image]

GPRS is displayed in JSF page, it's not a part of the dialog. However, it is visible since the dialog is transparent.

**Note:**
I'm using **primefaces-mobile-0.9.3.jar**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried overriding css style of the dialog component in my JSF page like that
(Remark the **!important** expression):

```
<p:dialog id="myDialog" header="ERROR" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true"
        style="background: gray !important;" appendToBody="true">
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Couldn't display the report!"
            onclick="dlg.hide()" type="button" />
</p:dialog>
```

And somehow the dialog is better now, it looks like:

[image]

However, overriding the general stylesheet of PrimeFaces library in my project might help me more for customizing the dialog.

The stylesheet's path in my dynamic web project: **WebContent/assets/css/style.css**
This could be reference for whom facing a similar problem.

Comment: You can override the stylesheets of primefaces. Take a look at this answer. [how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578494/how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces/8581199#8581199)

Answer (score 1):

When supplying a customized theme you're supposed to create a theme file. PrimeFaces' default theme is Aristo. For more info about how to create a custom theme see the [PrimeFaces Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_3.pdf) or the [mobile PrimeFaces Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_mobile_users_guide_0_9_3.pdf).

If you however don't want to create a complete theme the default theme is applied. To override styles in the applied theme you need to use `!important`. (You already discovered this though.)

A useful tool I use is FireBug. FireBug shows which CSS rules are applied to an element and also which rules are overridden.

Comment: The `!important` in stylesheets is not mandatory. It depends on how you're loading your stylesheets. If yours comes before PrimeFaces, then it would be overridden. The `!important` prevents that. But this is an ugly workaround. Better rearrange your `<h:outputStylesheet>` into `<h:body>` so that it's loaded *after* PrimeFaces one. OP's specific problem is slight different by the way.

Comment: @BalusC IIRC the PrimeFaces CSS is always loaded before the JSF page. Hence it is not possible to rearrange the style sheets.

Comment: @siebz0r, it is possible to rearrange the stylesheets whichever way you need it. See also [how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578494/how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces/8581199#8581199)

Answer (score -1):

To everyone who has this problem, I just find a solution whit this:

```
<p:dialog header="Header" widgetVar="dlg1" showEffect="pop"
            styleClass="ui-page-theme-a ui-bar-inherit">
```

Add the primefaces inherit class to the dialog, and it will appear by default.