# Primefaces p:panel width issue inside in p:layout

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces 3.5

When I set `p:dataTable` in `p:panel`, panel cannot display compatible width.
Problem is `table width` is larger than `panel width` as below capture image.

[image]

If I remove `p:layout`, it is ok.

I would like to get `panel with` lager than `table width`. Can it solve by using `jQuery`?

panel.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>   
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="260">
                left
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50">
                header
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true">
                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <p:panel header="Vehicle Information" id="vehicleInfoWizardPanel">  
                                <p:dataTable id="vehicleTable">
                                    <p:column headerText="Sr. No">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Registration No">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Model">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Engine No">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Chassis No">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Cubic Capacity">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Seating">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Weight (Ton)">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Sum Insured">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Product Type">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Add On">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Period (Month)">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Manufacture">
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Type Of Body">
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
                            </p:panel>
                </h:form>
             </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="260">
                Right
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="40">
                footer
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**update**

Even if I take panel width by jquery, it is always return `null`.

```
var width = $("#vehicleInfoWizardPanel").width();
alert(width);
```

But, I get amazing point. If I remove `h:form`, everything is ok without using jquery.

Comment: Why not simply use the `style` attribute of `p:panel` and set the `width` (e.g. `style = "width: 500px"`). Change the size as needed.

Comment: @Andy, fix width? I want 100% width, but It will be compatible with p:layout content

Comment: It was just a suggestion, 100% width doesn't work ?

Comment: I did like, it is not ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, the width is already at 100%. The panel's width is relative to its enclosing container. You would need to increase the width size to get the desired result. You could do this by using the `style` attribute of `p:panel` like so

```
<p:panel style="width: 200%" header="Vehicle Information"  id="vehicleInfoWizardPanel">
```

You could also override PrimeFaces CSS class `.ui-panel`. You might find this link useful

[How to override stylesheets of PrimeFaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578494/how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces)

Comment: wow, it is ok. I don't need to remove any tag. Thanks :) I just set 150%.