# background-image: url("") in CSS h:outputStylesheet is not loading

Tags: jsf-2, resources, background-image, outputstylesheet

Sorry if question is not properly asked. Image is showing fine in struts project but not in JSF2 project. All the css and buttons are rendering fine `except image that has url in css`.

**Folder structure**

```
resources -> css -> bootstrap.min.css
resources -> img -> glyphicons-halflings.png
```

**bootstrap.min.css**

```
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

**1 -** 
if I use `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css"/>` than background-image url generated is `http://localhost:8000/img/glyphicons-halflings.png` thus image not loading. It should be `http://localhost:8000/resources/img/glyphicons-halflings.png`

**2 -** If I use `<link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>` than

*Firefox -> Firebug -> Net tab {resources added multiple times}*

```
http://localhost:8000/resources/resources/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

not sure how to load image which is in css and applied on class.

***show EDIT icon as link to click to next page.***

```
 <h:outputLink value="edit.xhtml" >
                            <i class="icon-edit" ></i>
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{person.id}"/>
                        </h:outputLink>
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should be using the EL variable `#{resource}` in CSS to specify image resources.

```
background-image: url("#{resource['img/glyphicons-halflings.png']}");
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/changing-the-image-of-a-hcommandbutton-using-css/6926193#6926193)

Comment: Thanks. I will test it and mark your answer accepted asap. Can you reply to this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573178/jsf2-tomahawk-selectoneradio-render-label-separately . Easy for you.

Comment: For projects that generate their own css this is easy, but the are several plugins and themes that has their own bunch of css this is horrible to change every single external css for this. Is there any other way? I have the same problem but its very difficult to open every single css and change that line

Comment: @maxtorzito: checkout OmniFaces `UnmappedResourceHandler` (or ... use editor's builtin find&replace functionality, Eclipse has one even supporting regex)

Comment: @BalusC thank you i tested right now and works with any change in css file!!!! UnmappedResourceHandler is great!!  Thanks a lot