# JSF EL i18n in CSS files

Tags: css, jsf-2, el, spring-webflow-2

In my html pages I use the Spring message bean like so:

`#{ms.my_text_label}`

ms is of type ReloadableMessageSourceBundle and will translate my_text_label by looking in some resource bundle files. Can I make it possible to use this in my CSS files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm ignoring the Spring WebFlow part in the question and do as if the JSF project doesn't use any Spring artifacts.

---

You can just use EL in CSS files the usual way if you load the CSS file via [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html) instead of plain HTML `<link rel="stylesheet">`:

```
<h:outputStylehseet name="some.css" />
```

Note: this doesn't work for JS files, even not the ones loaded via [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html). EL is supported in CSS files for actually only one technical reason: being able to reference CSS background images via `#{resource}` mapping without the need to hardcode whole library and JSF mapping.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/changing-the-image-of-a-hcommandbutton-using-css/)

Comment: It seems like the resource thing works. But when I want to access my bean #{ms.xxxx} it just outputs everything like a string. Should any EL expression work?