# How to change the Home icon in Primefaces Breadcrumb?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to change the home icon of the Primefaces Breadcrumb with another icon but I can't find how.

I tried with CSS but it is not working for the icon:

```
.ui-breadcrumb {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    icon: url('resources/images/look/bandeau.png')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough with:

```
.ui-breadcrumb .ui-icon-home {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/look/bandeau.png']}");
    background-position: 0; /* asuming bandeau.png is a single image */
}
```

But you have to make sure two things:

- First, that you are overriding primefaces css correctly, you shouldn't need `!important`. See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774997/4056222). If you are doing it right, at least you will see that the default image dissapear.
- Second, you have to make sure that you are referring to the image correctly. In my code, I show how I do it myself, but it depends on your configuration so you should also check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926193/4056222).

Comment: Hello mrganser, it is working, thank you for your help and the link about CSS and Primefaces. However I think I will have to keep the default home icon as if I replace it, the place is very very small and I need to reduce a lot the size of the image I wanted there.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah... in my case for example I ended up creating some 16x16 icon from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to target that specific icon by doing so:

```
.ui-breadcrumb ul li .ui-menuitem-link.ui-home {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    background-image: url('resources/images/look/bandeau.png') !important;
}
```

Also check if the background image hyperlink is correct.

Comment: I just tried but it is not working, the icon is still the home picture.