# Reference a PrimeFaces image resource as CSS background image url

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

A bit new to the JSF and PrimeFaces and here I am, trying to load a resource (an image to be specific) and use it as a button's background, like this:

```
.greenButton {
    background: url(#{resource['images:ui-bg_gloss-wave_50_6eac2c_500x100.png']});  
}
```

and `<h:outputStyleSheet library="css" name="customStyles.css" />`, but it always resolved to:

```
.greenbutton {
    background: url("") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

in my stylesheet. I did refer to this question: 
"[How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6925733/934307)"
here and did the same, but looks like it won't work if it was a PrimeFaces resource? Should I do it differently in this case?

The image is located here: `/resources/primefaces-start/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_50_6eac2c_500x100.png` and is loaded by the `theme.css` under `/resources/primefaces-start` FWIW.

My default theme is the `start`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>start</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and I'm actually trying to override some of the theme aspects like the button colors in this case.

Here's my folder structure including the `customStyles.css` file that I'm modifying:

```
webapp
  - pages
  - resources
    - css
      -customStyles.css
```

Comment: Missing "primefaces-start"?

Comment: @chRyNaN, it's included in the classpath (inside `start-1.0.8.jar`).

Comment: Show the full `h:outputStylesheet` and is start your default theme?

Comment: @Kukeltje, added those details to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `library` the wrong way. The `library` can never be like `images`, `css`, `js`, etc in a sensible way. See also the [bottom part of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926193) on the question you found, which in turn references further to a must-read Q&A for JSF starters [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Given an image URL of `/resources/primefaces-start/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_50_6eac2c_500x100.png`, the `library` part is clearly `primefaces-start`.

So, this should do:

```
.greenButton {
    background: url(#{resource['primefaces-start:images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_50_6eac2c_500x100.png']});  
}
```