# Access JSF resource from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I want to access a JSF resources ( under `WebPages/resources/img`) from a javascript function like:

```
function hideSpinner() {
    arguments[i].poster = './img/sppiner.png';
}
```

I have tried `arguments[i].poster = "${resource['img/sppiner.png']}";` and `arguments[i].poster = '${resource[\'img/sppiner.png\']}';` but it doesnt work..

What Can I do?

Comment: Try `#{request.contextPath}/resources/img/sppiner.png`. It will work if your javascript function is located into a facelet page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EL expressions are only evaluated in Facelets (XHTML) files and in CSS files loaded via `<h:outputStylesheet>`. They are not evaluated in JS files loaded via `<h:outputScript>`.

You basically need to render an inline script which sets a (global) JavaScript variable which the JS file should in turn refer to.

```
<h:outputScript>var spinnerImage = "${resource['img/sppiner.png']}";</h:outputScript>
<h:outputScript name="js/some.js" />
```

```
arguments[i].poster = spinnerImage;
```

Much cleaner, however, is to set the image as a CSS background image associated with a specific CSS style class and then just let JavaScript set that style class on the desired element. As said, you can use EL expressions in CSS files loaded via `<h:outputStylesheet>`. See also a.o. [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url).

Comment: great answer, if the file js/some.js has javascript file references then these return 404 error as they are not referenced in the h:outputScript way, do you have any idea how to resolve without updating all references in js/some.js?