# h:outputStylesheet inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, uirepeat, outputstylesheet

I'm trying to use  to output a stylesheet link for every element of an ArrayList.  This code produces no result:

```xhtml
<ui:repeat value="#{includer.css}" var="ss">
  <h:outputStylesheet name="#{ss}" library="css" />
</ui:repeat>
```

However, if i change the Strings in the ArrayList to be full paths and replace  h:outputStylesheet with plain html like :

```xhtml
<ui:repeat value="#{includer.css}" var="ss">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${ss}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

then it works as expected. The problem with this is i have some EL expressions in some css files and it seems they are not being evaluated,  I assume because i'm referencing them directly like that.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: EL expressions in stylesheets won't be evaluated regardless of how you generate the HTML. Stylesheetsare loaded direct by the browser, without going through anything that will evaluate EL.

Comment: @EJP: actually, they will be, but only when loaded via `<h:outputStylesheet>` (and you've restarted the webapp after adding an EL expression to an already-loaded stylesheet; this is namely remembered applicationwide on a per-stylesheet basis).

Comment: @BalusC How so? When it generates an HTML link element?

Comment: @EJP: primarily to support `#{resource}` in URL selectors for e.g. background images and fonts. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url/6926193#6926193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:outputStylesheet>` (and `<h:outputScript>`) needs to be present during view build time in order to let the JSF resource management to properly pickup them. The `<ui:repeat>`, however, runs during view render time only, it would be too late for JSF to perform relocation actions (moving to bottom of head or body, etc).

Replace it by `<c:forEach>`.

```
<c:forEach items="#{includer.css}" var="ss">
    <h:outputStylesheet name="#{ss}" library="css" />
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, a library name of `css` is wrong. Carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thank you, sir. Very interesting read on the resource library as well.