# Reference a image resource as CSS background image url

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I got this in my css file:

```
background: #1484e6 url("/webapp/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_22_1484e6_40x40.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces-excite-bike") 50% 50% repeat;
```

How would I reference to the image instead of using this full url? Because the basename "webapp" could change, so this will not always work.

I tried using this, but it won't work:

```
#{resource['images:ui-bg_diagonals-thick_22_1484e6_40x40.png']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong library name. The part before `:` in the resource identifier represents the library name. You specified `images`, while it should be `primefaces-excite-bike` as indicated by the `ln` request parameter in the URL.

So, this should do:

```
#{resource['primefaces-excite-bike:images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_22_1484e6_40x40.png']}
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url/)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thanks for also referring me to related information!