# JSF 2.0 graphicImage: set background-image by css

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a commandLink primefaces with an internal graphicImage (JSF 2 with Primefaces 5).

Following code works fine:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{mybean.mymethod()}" process="@this">

   <h:graphicImage name="images/one.jpg" 
   rendered="#{myBean.test.size() == 0" />

</p:commandLink>
```

Unfortunately, I have any graphicImage in my application so I would like set image in a css class.

I think about something:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{mybean.mymethod()}" process="@this">

   <h:graphicImage styleClass="myClass" 
   rendered="#{myBean.test.size() == 0" />

</p:commandLink>
```

where my css file is following:

```
.myClass {
     background-image: url('/myApplication/resources/images/one.jpg');
}
```

but doesn't work.

Is it possible? Otherwise, how can I replace graphicImage component? I try with img tag or adding a class in commandLink component with a background-image but doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicated by? I found some answers but not working for this. Do I found wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
background-image: url("#{resource['images/one.jpg']}");
```

And you can just use the styleClass directly on the `p:commandLink` (no need for the `h:graphicImage`).

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url/6926193#6926193) reading on the matter.

Comment: I had already seen your post. I try so this but doesn't work: <p:commandLink action="#{mybean.mymethod()}" process="@this" styleClass="myClass">
...
</p:commandLink> where my css class is following: .myClass {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/one.jpg']}") !important;
} Using inspect from browser, I see myClass with background image correctly, but I don't see image...

Comment: Perhaps because my commandLink is inside a datagrid? My structure complete is following: <p:dataGrid id="grid"
 columns="2" 
 styleClass="GRID-STYLE"
 var="attribute"
 value="#{bean.values}">
 
  <f:facet name="header" >
   <p:commandLink action="#{mybean.mymethod()}" process="@this" styleClass="myClass"> ... </p:commandLink>
  </f:facet>
  
  <p:row>
                <p:column >
  ...
  </p:row>
</p:dataGrid>

Comment: Do you include css with h:outputStylesheet? You must... if not what is the complete folder structure?

Comment: I had done already. Using inspect from browser, I see myClass with background image correctly, but I don't see image on browser..

Comment: If I replace commandLink with commandButton works... probably commandLink doesn't load correctly images from resources... This questions is not never done...

Comment: SOLVED also for commandLink. It's enough add width and height to class css because image probably is load with 0px