# Setting a background-image URL in JSF stylesheet resource through Sass

Tags: css, jsf, sass

I just started to work with CSS and espacialy Sass. What I tryed to do for the last hour was to set a background image from my source folder from my `scss.` file.

[image]

I tryed several ways of accesing my directory. But not a single one worked.
My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) always tells me that it can not resolve the directory.
I tried:

```
background-image:url('${resource(dir: "images", file: "bg.png")}');
background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-image:url(../images:bg.png);
background-image:url('../images:bg.png');
```

And also as refered in this topic [How to refernce JSF image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url/6926193#6926193/%22How%20to%20reference%20JSF%20image%22):

```
background-image: url("#{resource['images/bg.png']}");
```

I hope one of you can provide me with a solution.

**EDIT**

this line gives no error in the `.scss` file:

```
background-image:url("/resources/images/bg.png");
```

but it precompiles wrong in the `.css` file because the directory can not be resolved anymore.

**EDIT**

the code that does not get marked as problem in either `.scss` or `.css` is:

```
 background-image:url("../../../src/resources/images/bg.png");
```

But it still does not work my background remains white.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

The problem was, that I tryed to access my java resources folder.
But I had to access a child of the webapp folder. As the `.WAR` is build from that context. That means this was the solution.

```
background-image:url("./images/bg.gif");
```

while my `images` folder is a child of my `webapp` folder.