# How to display uploaded image via CSS

Tags: java, css, jsf

i want to upload an image via primefaces:fileUpload and then display it on a div for example with css.
I can already save the image on the server:

```
public void upload() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        if (logo != null) {
            File fileImage = new File(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"), "uploads.png");
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(logo.getContents()));
            if (fileImage.exists()) {
                fileImage.delete();
            }
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", fileImage);
        }
    }
```

And then i tried to get the web path to the file but that didn't worked:

```
public String getImagePath(){
        File fileImage = new File(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"), "uploads.png");
        Set<String> set = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourcePaths(fileImage.getAbsolutePath());
        return set.iterator().next();
    }
```

I need something like this:

> /ewarehouse/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2&v=6.2&pfdrid=f52e395e4f38c09a1990e8f9d0c5806d&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=true

Can someone help me or has a other way to do this ?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I dont think that will help. I just need to generate the webpath to a file.Or maybe it does help but i dont get it

Comment: Then just create a servlet

Comment: Yes, @JasperdeVries is right. You decide where you place the file so you can decide how to access it. Nothing special to it. Only thing is that if you need a 'dynamic' path in CSS it is better to put that css part in the xhtml file. A little easier to get it parsed/processed then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url

Comment: @Kukeltje Can i save a image in the resources at runtime? I thought that didn't work.

Comment: It sometimes works,but you should not do that. I posted the link as an example on how to use images in CSS. You should not always take things litterally but also look at the 'concepts'. You can save them anywhere in the filesystem or in a database and via a servlet (like @JasperdeVries mentioned) provide a virtual path for it to be downloaded.

Comment: I will try that thanks for your so far.

Comment: Hi, 'answers' should be in answers and not in edits to the question. And your 'url' with EL in it indeed looks weird and does not seem to be needed at all that way. Why do you do it like that (and 'it does not work other ways' is not the right answer ;-)) Especially since in one location your do `//` instead of `#{'/'}`

Comment: @Kukeltje i did it like cause my url has 2 slashe. I dont know where that comes from but i need to call `/ewarehouse/images//dynamic#/?file=uploads.png` and i didn't know how to escape 2 slashes in a row. Maybe you have  a solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me to create a servlet and refered to the file position.

`background-image: url('#{'/'}ewarehouse#{'/'}images//dynamic#{'/'}?file=uploads.png')`

In css it look a bit weird but this way it worked Thanks for the answer to @JasperdeVries and @Kukeltje

Comment: Why do you have the single slashes in 'EL' ? I fail to see the need for that

Comment: I failed to escape a single slash so i did it this way

Comment: why do you (think you) **need** to escape a single slash?